# php Uploading multiple files with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I've managed to upload multiple files using my current php and html form and wanted to fancy it up a bit with some ajax and automatically submitting the form. I've hidden the 'file' input and submit button so the form is handeled by the js (mentioning this incase it may affect form submission, form does submission and I've checked via HTTP headers). The ajax section of my js is what I normally use for ajax and standard forms, however when i submit the form my $_FILES is empty so I guess I'm not using the ajax correctly here? What do I need to change in my ajax to handle file uploads?

```
    $("#add_button").click(function(e)
   {
       e.preventDefault();
       $("#folder_open_id").trigger("click");
       $("#folder_open_id").change(function()
       {
          $("#folder_upload").submit();
       });
   });


   $("#folder_upload").submit(function(event)
   {
        var formdata   =   $(this).serialize();
        event.preventDefault();

        $.ajax
        ({
           url: "index.php",
           type: "POST",
           data: formdata,
           success: function(response) { $("#response_div").html(response); },
           error: function(response) { alert(response); }
        });
    });
```

php

```
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{
    if(!empty($_FILES['files']['name'][0]))
    {

        $files      =   $_FILES['files'];
        define('CPATH', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/uploads/");
        $uploaded   =   array();

        foreach($files['name'] as $position => $file_name)
        {
            $file_temp  =   $files['tmp_name'][$position];
            $file_new   =   "./uploads/" . $files['name'][$position];

                if(move_uploaded_file($file_temp, $file_new))
                    echo "success";
                else
                    echo "fail, temp: " . $file_temp . " new: " . $file_new;
        }
    }
    else 
        echo '<pre>', print_r($_POST, 1), '</pre>';
}
```

so `empty($_FILES['files']['name'][0]`is returning true and the print_r($_POST) is empty it seems.

html form

```
<form id="folder_upload" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
              <input type="file" class="hide" name="files[]" id="folder_open_id" multiple directory webkitdirectory mozdirectory/>
              <input type="submit" class="hide" value="upload" id="folder_open_upload" />
        </form>
```

Here is my js after Mephoros answer, my $_FILES array still seems to be empty:

```
$.ajax
    ({
       url: "index.php",
       type: "POST",
       data: new FormData($(this)),
       processData: false,
       contentType: 'multipart/form-data; charset=UTF-8',
       success: function(response) { $("#response_div").html(response); },
       error: function(response) { alert(response); }
    });
```

Comment: A little off topic but might be usefull: use console.log instead of alert, this will make it alot easier to debug.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on some preliminary research, utilize FormData and set processing and contentType to false.

```
$.ajax({
  // ...
  data: new FormData($(this)),
  processData: false,
  contentType: false,
  // ...
});
```

Sources:

- http://portfolio.planetjon.ca/2014/01/26/submit-file-input-via-ajax-jquery-easy-way/
- http://abandon.ie/notebook/simple-file-uploads-using-jquery-ajax

See: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Using_FormData_Objects

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. I have edited my question with your suggestions and my $_FILES still appears to be empty. Any ideas?

Comment: Hmm actually the sources suggest setting `contentType` to false. The second one is a particularly detailed approach; perhaps give something similar a try? I'll edit my answer based on the sources.

Comment: $_FILES i still empty after those changes. I'll have a look through some of the articles you linked.