# how to alert multiple input file values in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a file input field  . In that user can choose multiple files for uploading. For that purpose i want to alert and check values which is retrieving correctly .

And i using Form-data to get values . is it possible to alert Form-data values

Thanks in advance

Comment: what you have try so far?

Comment: my aim is to upload multiple files at one request . i can able to upload single image in ajax . but while coming to multiple image at once . i have no idea . so i am trying to alert those values .

Comment: i used this http://jsfiddle.net/paulftw/umcFW/183/. but no idea . its not working

Comment: visit <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27500237/php-uploading-multiple-files-with-ajax?rq=1>?

Finally problem solved.

Comment: Please add code snippets showing what you have tried before. If you found a solution, you can answer your own question and show the solution there or take the question down.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can get all selected files via the files attribute.

```
var x = document.getElementById("myFile"); 
var txt = ""; 
if ('files' in x) {
    if (x.files.length == 0) {
        txt = "Select one or more files.";
    } else {
        for (var i = 0; i < x.files.length; i++) {
            txt += "<br><strong>" + (i+1) + ". file</strong><br>";
            var file = x.files[i];
            if ('name' in file) {
                txt += "name: " + file.name + "<br>";
            }
            if ('size' in file) {
                txt += "size: " + file.size + " bytes <br>";
            }
        }
    } 
}
alert(txt);
```

[See here for documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_fileupload_files.asp)